# Preserving backslashes when reading from a variable in a posix script

Tags: posix

I was hoping someone might be able to please lead me on the right path using POSIX script... I've got a variable that contains a network path UNC.  When I refer to this variable, it chops the backslashes off to what they are supposed to look like (\\\\ becomes \\ and \\ becomes \), which is great for when I need to use this variable in a networking capacity.  But I'd like to refer to the UNC in its original state by passing along what's literally in this variable to display on screen.  How can I accomplish that?

```
UNC="\\\\192.168.1.1\\Backup"

echo $UNC
printf '%s' $UNC
```

I would expect to see:
\\\\192.168.1.1\\Backup

But I see:
\\192.168.1.1\Backup